# Entity Framework - "Compiling transformation: The metadatafile ../IDE/EntityFramework.dll wasn't found"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I've been having this problem for a while now, but found a cheat way to avoid it.

Everytime I create a new .edmx file, update a current .edmx, or basically do anything that has to do with Entity Framework, I get the following error:

> Compiling transformation: The metadatafile ../IDE/EntityFramework.dll wasn't found

Everytime I've worked in a group, I've avoided this error by simply letting the other members of the group update the .edmx file. But as I'm working alone at the current moment, I've had enough of this, and wish to put this to an end.

I've installed Entity Framework through nuget, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling EF with no luck at all.

Am I the only one with this problem? And do any of you have a solution to this strange error?

Please ask for code or anything you need, and I'll provide.

Answer (score 0):

**Managed to solve the problem on my own.**

As I'm working on a laptop with two drives (SSD & HDD), I've installed VS on my HDD (D:/).

I changed my environment variable `VS120COMNTOOLS` to be `D:\Programmer\Visual Studio Ultimate\Common7\Tools\` instead of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tool\`, restarted VS and everything now works.

I've had this problem for a while, and finally managed to fix it. If anyone else has this problem and don't quite know what exactly I did, please tell so, and I'll compile some images of the steps, as this is the most frustrating error I've ever encountered.